# Self-contained rmarkdown file contains only some embedded images

Tags: r-markdown

I'm seeing different behaviour in an R Markdown (Rmd) file depending on how I reference the image I'd like to embed in an HTML document. In the simple example below, the second image is embedded in the document, but the first (using the R chunk) is not.

````
---
title: "title"
output:
  html_document:
    mode: selfcontained
    theme: null
---

```{r packages, echo=FALSE}
library(htmltools)
```

```{r imgTest, echo=FALSE}
img(src = "http://placehold.it/350x150")
```

<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
````

This is the output in the HTML (for the relevant bit):

```
<p><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/></p>
<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG<SNIPPED>"></p>
```

In summary, using the htmltools function `img()` within a code chunk does not embed the image but instead it remains a link.

For various reasons, I need the document to be truly self-contained (no links) and to also avoid raw HTML.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and offer a solution? I've tried a variety of chunk options without success so far.

Comment: Do you need to use the `ìmg()` function? Why not just use `cat("<img src=\"http://placehold.it/350x150\"/>")` inside a chunk with option `results='asis' `

Comment: Thanks! That's a simple and neat idea.